# PCS Cluster with Shared IP on different interface

Tags: cluster-computing, pacemaker

I am creating a Fedora PCS Cluster for HAProxy.  I have it running on VMWare, and am following this guide, and get to this step of adding a IPAddr2 resource: http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/_adding_a_resource.html

The only difference is that I need my cluster heartbeat/comms on one NIC/subnet, and my shared resource IP on a different NIC/subnet.

My internal comms is Node1=192.160.0.1 and Node2=192.168.0.2, and my resource ip is 10.0.0.1

How do I use this command in this situation:

```
pcs resource create ClusterIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
    ip=192.168.0.120 cidr_netmask=32 op monitor interval=30s
```

If I add it as above, I get this:

```
[root@node-01 .pcs]# pcs status
Cluster name: mycluster
Last updated: Tue Oct 28 09:10:13 2014
Last change: Tue Oct 28 09:00:13 2014 via cibadmin on node-02
Stack: corosync
Current DC: node-02 (2) - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.11-1.fc20-9d39a6b
2 Nodes configured
1 Resources configured


Online: [ node-01 node-02 ]

Full list of resources:

 ClusterIP      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Stopped

Failed actions:
    ClusterIP_start_0 on node-01 'unknown error' (1): call=7, status=complete, last-rc-change='Tue Oct 28 09:00:13 2014', queued=0ms, exec=27ms
    ClusterIP_start_0 on node-02 'unknown error' (1): call=6, status=complete, last-rc-change='Tue Oct 28 09:00:13 2014', queued=0ms, exec=27ms
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to specify the network device as mentioned by Daniel, e.g.

```
pcs resource create ClusterIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=10.0.0.1 cidr_netmask=32 nic=eth0 op monitor interval=30s
```

Since you are running two node cluster, you don't have a fencing device. So you have to disable the STONITH setting but it is not recommended for production environment.

```
pcs property set stonith-enabled=false
```

The virtual ip address should be activated automatically.

```
#pcs status resources

    Full list of resources:
    ClusterIP      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started:node-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the NIC. If your first NIC is eth0 and second is eth1. you can create the resource with this :

```
pcs resource create ClusterIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=10.0.0.1 cidr_netmask=32 nic=eth1:0  op monitor interval=30s
```

You can also use only eth1, but i prefer to use sub interface for my floating IP address. You can create more than one floating IP addresses on one NIC, but you need to configure each on unique sub interface.